# virtual attributes with validators, splitting/joining a column value to create them

Tags: php, lithium

I have an existing SQL table the schema of which I cannot modify, and I would like to create a Lithium data model for it. The problem is that one column contains multiple "fields" separated by a special character.

E.g.

```
data = "username|email|age"
```

I would need to:

- split the value of the column after the row was read, and create
  "virtual" attributes
- be able to assign to these virtual attributes
- join the virtual attributes to create a valid column value before save
- create validators for the virtual attributes
- use html->form to create form fields for the virtual attributes

I tried to figure out how to do this, but there seems to be no easy way. Not even a hard way :) Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magic virtual attributes aren't supported in Lithium out of the box. There is an ongoing work and discussion about that here https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/pull/569.

That said, you can almost solve this problem with instance methods in your Model + filters on save and find.

- An after find filter, which sets `username`, `email` and `age`,
  attributes to your entity after reading it.
- A before save filter, which join those attributes in a `data` attributes before saving the entity, and unsets `username`, `email` and `age` (to avoid saving them).

Maybe you'll need Model instance methods too like

```
public function username($entity) {
      /* split here $entity->data by "|" and keep only what do you want */
      return $username;
}
```

Then you can call anywhere $user->username() to get the username only.

That should solve your problem until this feature will be shipped in Lithium.

Comment: I prefer callbacks to filters, but I guess this is sort of Lithium's way to solve things :) Thanks!

Comment: Filters are callbacks. And you can override save() and find() methods in a BaseModel class too ;)

Comment: I think I will just wait for the virtual attributes branch to get merged :) Or maybe I just merge it myself... I already had to do that with some part of the data branch, as SQLite support is somewhat broken in master.